# Sort cells in numerical values but leave zeros/blanks in original position

Tags: excel

I need to sort a range in a row numerically but leave the zeros in their original cells. Additionally, I need Excel to treat zero values as zeroes and not blanks.

I have tried =IF combined with =ISBLANK for the sorting issue. I fixed the blanks showing as zero using the IF function but it will not allow me to combine both issues.

Comment: Some sample data and the expected result would be really helpful here, if you can [edit] your question.